# If user's email and password doesn't match the other codes won't run and return an error. But if does, then it will work fine in google firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to show the error if user's email and password doesn't match. But can't figure out what I've been doing wrong. When I login with the wrong password it takes me straight to the home page. But what I am trying to do is: if password doesn't match then it won't take me anywhere.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSignInWithGoogle, useSignInWithEmailAndPassword, useSendPasswordResetEmail } from 
'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc';
import auth from '../../firebase.init';
import './Login.css';
import LoadingSpinner from '../Loadingspinner/LoadingSpinner';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import axios from 'axios';
const Login = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    // let the user go where he came from if he logged in
    const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";
    // handle google sign in
    const [signInWithGoogle, googleUser, googleLoading, googleError] = useSignInWithGoogle(auth);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (googleUser) {
            // console.log(googleUser.user);
            navigate(from, { replace: true });
        };
    }, [navigate, googleUser, from]);
    if (googleLoading) {
        <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
    };

    // handle email sign in
    const [
        signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        emailUser,
        emailLoading,
        emailError,
    ] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (emailUser) {
            // navigate(from, { replace: true });
        }
    }, [emailUser, navigate, from]);
    // if (emailError) {
    //     console.log(emailError.message)
    // };
    /*     if (emailLoading) {
            <LoadingSpinner></LoadingSpinner>
        }; */
    // get user infos
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });
    // set errors
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
        email: "",
        password: "",
        others: ""
    });

    // send password reset email
    const [sendPasswordResetEmail, sending, error] = useSendPasswordResetEmail(
        auth
    );
    // handle password reset mail
    const handleResetPass = async () => {
        if (userInfo.email) {
            await sendPasswordResetEmail(userInfo.email);
            toast.success('Reset email has been sent.')
        }
        else {
            toast.error('Please try again')
        }
    }


    // get email
    const handleEmailChange = e => {
        const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        if (emailRegex.test(e.target.value)) {
            setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, email: e.target.value });
            setErrors({ ...errors, email: '' });
        } else {
            setErrors({ ...errors, email: 'Please Provide a valid email' });
            setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, email: '' });
        }
    };



    // get password
    const handlePasswordChange = e => {
        setUserInfo({ ...userInfo, password: e.target.value })
    };

    // handle login
    const handleLogin = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // console.log(email);
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInfo.email, userInfo.password);
        const email = userInfo.email;
        const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/token', { email });
        // console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.token);
        navigate(from, { replace: true });

    };
    // handle google sign in
    const handleGoogleSignin = () => {
        signInWithGoogle();
    };


    return (
        <div className="mt-5">
            <div className="w-50 mx-auto mt-5 login-form p-5">
                <h3 className="text-center mb-3 login-title">Log in</h3>
                <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control onChange={handleEmailChange} type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                        {errors?.email && <p className='text-danger'>{errors.email}</p>}
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control onChange={handlePasswordChange} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Button variant="danger" type="submit" className="w-100">
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Form>
                <Button onClick={handleGoogleSignin} variant="" type="submit" className="w-100 my-2 google-btn mt-4">
                    <FcGoogle className='g-icon'></FcGoogle> Sign in with Google
                </Button>
                <button onClick={handleResetPass} className="btn btn-link">Forgot password?</button>
                <p>Don't have an account? <button onClick={() => navigate('/signup')} className="btn btn-link">Create an account</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the error state of the signInWithEmailAndPassword  in a try/catch block.

In handleLogin():

```
try {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInfo.email, userInfo.password);
    const email = userInfo.email;
    const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/token", { email });
    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.token);
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
} catch (error) {
    //handle error state
}
```

Comment: I've did this. But it's showing me error and taking me to home page. But I don't want it to change its route if the user put a wrong password. Thanks for the response.